# Tkinter freeze and won't load the result on screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to make an app that calculates the smallest common for you, but for some reason whenever i run it, tkinter seems to just freeze and i don't know what the error seems to be. I suspect that it's the myLabel part, since I can still read the result inside the Terminal.

Thanks in advance~

```
from tkinter import * 


root = Tk()
root.title("I can find the smallest common, unless you enter letters... I'm dyslexic.")


numbers_list = []

global numbers
numbers = Entry(root, width = 10, borderwidth = 5, state = DISABLED)
numbers.pack()
numbers.insert(0, "")
#
def button_click():
    #each gets a button
    get_smallest_common = Button(root, text = 'Confirm your number!'
    , command = smallest_common)
    get_smallest_common.pack()
    

    get_smallest_common = Button(root, text = 'Undo!'
    , command = lambda: undo())
    get_smallest_common.pack()

    get_smallest_common = Button(root, text = 'Start the search!'
    , command = lambda: find_the_s_common())
    get_smallest_common.pack()



#disable the start button
def switch():
    myButton['state'] = DISABLED
    #configure helps bringing a disabled thing back to normal state
    numbers.configure(state = "normal")

def smallest_common():
    #add to the list for late use
    numbers_list.append(numbers.get())
    print(numbers_list)  
    numbers.delete(0, END)

def undo():
    #add to the list for late use    
    numbers_list.pop()
    print(numbers_list)  
    numbers.delete(0, END)

def find_the_s_common():
    process_list = []
    condition = True
    x = 0

                
    while condition:
    #the multiplication keep rising till count is 3
        a = int(x) + 1
        x = a
        
            
        #loop to multiply the number with x + 1
        for number in numbers_list:
            y = int(number) * int(a)
            process_list.append(y)
            
            #check whether the result has been added to append into list
            if y in process_list:
                
                #check whether the list contains two duplicates to 
                if process_list.count(y) == 3:
                    condition = False
                    result = 'The number is ' + str(y) + '!'
                    print(result)
                else:
                        continue
            else:
                continue
    myLabel = Label(root, text = result)
    myLabel.pack()


#combine the two function for myButton
def button_click_switch():
    button_click()
    switch()

myButton = Button(root, text = 'Click me to start'
, command = lambda: [button_click(), switch()])
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, you have problem if the numbers entered is less than 3. As a result, one simple way is to decrease the condition to 2 and if a single number is entered the result is the number itself, if 2 or more no freezing.

NOTE: Freezing here is actually, `while` loop is running as condition is always True, because of `process_list.count(y) == 3` will always be `False` if less than 3 number entered.

See my suggestion:

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()
root.title("I can find the smallest common, unless you enter letters... I'm dyslexic.")

numbers_list = []

global numbers
numbers = Entry(root, width = 10, borderwidth = 5, state = DISABLED)
numbers.pack()
numbers.insert(0, "")
#
def button_click():
    #each gets a button
    get_smallest_common = Button(root, text = 'Confirm your number!', command = smallest_common)
    get_smallest_common.pack()
    get_smallest_common = Button(root, text = 'Undo!', command = lambda: undo())
    get_smallest_common.pack()
    get_smallest_common = Button(root, text = 'Start the search!'   , command = lambda: find_the_s_common())
    get_smallest_common.pack()

#disable the start button
def switch():
    myButton['state'] = DISABLED
    #configure helps bringing a disabled thing back to normal state
    numbers.configure(state = "normal")

def smallest_common():
    #add to the list for late use
    numbers_list.append(numbers.get())
    print(numbers_list)  
    numbers.delete(0, END)

def undo():
    #add to the list for late use   
    numbers_list.pop()
    print(numbers_list)  
    numbers.delete(0, END)

def find_the_s_common():
    process_list = []
    condition = True
    x = 0
    if len(numbers_list) == 1: # RETURN IF THE LIST HAS A SINGLE VALUE
        result = 'The number is ' + str(numbers_list[0]) + '!'
    else:
        while condition:
        #the multiplication keep rising till count is 3
            a = int(x) + 1
            x = a   
            #loop to multiply the number with x + 1
            for number in numbers_list:
                y = int(number) * int(a)
                process_list.append(y)
                #check whether the result has been added to append into list
                if y in process_list:
                    #check whether the list contains two duplicates to 
                    if process_list.count(y) == 2: # DECREASE THE CONDITIONS TO 2
                        condition = False
                        result = 'The number is ' + str(y) + '!'
                        print(result)
                    else:
                            continue
                else:
                    continue
    myLabel = Label(root, text = result)
    myLabel.pack()

#combine the two function for myButton
def button_click_switch():
    button_click()
    switch()

myButton = Button(root, text = 'Click me to start', command = lambda: [button_click(), switch()])
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Suggestion to add two conditons;
(1) create a condition until at least 1 number is entered! `if len(numbers_list) == 0`, loop to enter a number.

(2) create a condition, until N number is added,  let's say user must enter at least 3 numbers, change `process_list.count(y) == 3` to `process_list.count(y) == N` and add condition `if len(numbers_list) != N`, loop to enter more numbers.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much, I completely forgot about that situation, you really are a life saver!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do not forget to up-vote and accept answers, if they are solving your problem or answer your question.